# How can I use conditional formatting in an Excel table using structured references?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I believe I am correct in saying that a reference to a column in a table (e.g. `table1["col1"]`) is known as a structured reference as opposed to an absolute reference (e.g. `A1:A5`).

I would like to know if it is possible to use structured references in a table. This post: [Structured table references in conditional formatting formulas](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bc99aaa6-597d-40b8-8304-1b578554ce5e/structured-table-references-in-conditional-formatting-formulas?forum=excel) suggests that it is possible using `INDIRECT()`however I cannot figure out how to achieve what I need. I'll explain.

Take this contrived example:
[image]
This is a table. I would like the value in `col2` to be coloured green if it is equal to the value in `col1`, and I'd like to use conditional formatting to do it. Essentially I want it to look like this:
[image]

I attempted to "Use a formula to determine which cells to format", the formula is `=INDIRECT("Table1[col1]")=INDIRECT("Table1[col2]")`:
[image]

But none of the cells changed their formatting.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: When there are multiple columns in the table one must use the full reference `tblName[columnName]` in their reference.

Comment: thanks @ScottCraner, I tried that but it still didn't work. I updated the post accordingly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Include the table name and add the *@* symbol to reference row for row.

```
=INDIRECT("Table1[@col1]")=INDIRECT("Table1[@col2]")
```

[image]
    <sub>click for larger image</sub>

Comment: That works great, much better than having a specific column letter.
Shame we can't just reference a column in the same table like [@[col1]] in conditional formatting.

Comment: This kind of formula `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table10[[#Data],[Process1]:[Process18]] & "_" & RIGHT(Table10[[#Headers],[Process1]:[Process18]],LEN(Table10[[#Headers],[Process1]:[Process18]])-7),Table10[[#Data],['#Experiment processes]]))` works for me if I put it in some cell. But it doesn't work if I put it in the conditional formatting field! Why?!

Comment: Is there a way to use a table name as a cell range?

Answer (score 0):

For me the following works: first cell of the column to be formatted is selected, then conditional formatting --> use a formula --> edit rule: put in table column to be formatted = column to compare to
the first cell should be formatted now. Then I used format painter for the rest of the column, in your case Col2. it worked for me, hope it works for you as well. - Martijn

Disregard: After rechecking the effects, I noted the conditioning does not work.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is your answer better than the accepted one? If you don't have something substantial to add or the old answer is now outright dangerous, please do not answer questions that are this old.