# "Structured references" work in equation, but same equation doesn't work in "structured references"

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have this formula with *"structured references"*:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table10[[#Data],[Process1]:[Process18]] & "_" & RIGHT(Table10[[#Headers],[Process1]:[Process18]],LEN(Table10[[#Headers],[Process1]:[Process18]])-7),Table10[[#Data],['#Experiment processes]]))
```

which works great if I input it in any cell... But If I try to use it with Excel's *"conditional formatting"* it doesn't work! I get this error:

[image]

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1517823/how-can-i-use-conditional-formatting-in-an-excel-table-using-structured-referenc) post but I don't understand how to apply the described solution in my case. I would kindly ask you toe be descriptive, i.e. explain why do we use something etc...

Comment: It would be useful to get an understanding of your data structure in order to help!

Comment: @karl I don't think this is needed. I only wonder why the **syntax** which is clearly correct (a) works if I put it in the *"cell"* and (b) fails to work if I put it as a formula in the *"conditional formating"*

Comment: how are you using the formula in your conditional formatting? Can you get a more simplified version to work?

Comment: Having sample data that can be used to reproduce the problem may help someone help you find a solution.